# USB3 to Ethernet adapter neither properly detected nor functional

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, kernel, ethernet

My laptop is a Dell XPS 15 (9550) running ubuntu 15.10.
My USB to Ethernet adapter is an Aukey CB-C17 (http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B013HUDG0U).

My question is simple: How to make appear the ethernet interface so I can configure it?

My kernel seems to detect the device almost properly:

```
[    1.663215] usb 4-1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.680336] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[    1.680337] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[    1.680338] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[    1.680338] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    1.680339] usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
```

Note that the SerialNumber is odd.

Unpluging and plugin again the USB3 device produce 2 extra lines:

```
[20385.100994] usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[20385.261087] usb 4-1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[20385.277670] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[20385.277678] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[20385.277683] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[20385.277687] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[20385.277690] usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[20390.281085] usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[20390.288426] usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
```

Lspci:

```
$ lspci -nn

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

Some other infomation:

```
$ lshw

*-usb UNCLAIMED
                               description: Generic USB device
                               product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
                               vendor: Realtek
                               physical id: 1
                               bus info: usb@4:1.1
                               version: 30.00
                               serial: 000000000000
                               capabilities: usb-3.00
                               configuration: speed=5000Mbit/s
```

Yet ifconfig does not see this device as an interface:

```
$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
[..snip..]
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:6d:c7
```

The second is my wireless adapter.

Per suggestion:

```
$ sudo modprobe r8152
```

Produces no new logs from kernel (dmesg -w stayed the same). But when executed against historical kernel messages (I took some messages before and after "r8152" match):

```
[   13.114909] usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   13.117934] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   13.117936] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   13.117938] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   13.117940] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   13.122633] usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[   13.126856] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0
-3.2)
[   13.131446] usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[   13.131521] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[   13.136022] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
```

Cold boot with device inserted, dmesg logs show the U1 and U2 errors too:

```
[   13.114909] usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   13.122633] usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[   13.131446] usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
```

As proposed, adding r8152 module to `/etc/modules` did solve one part of the problem: the ethernet adapter now appear in `ifconfig -a`. However automatic or manual configuration does not seem to make it able to communicate.

Kernel-wise, I've tested all stable and non-stable kernels, including  Mainline(http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/) which proves to be the best for some hardware strictly related to the laptop.

Comment: Please run these commands and then edit your question to add the result: `sudo modprobe r8152` and then: `dmesg | grep r8152` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Did it, thanks for your suggestion and your welcome.

Comment: I think this is the issue: *Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.* Do you have a second USB3 port to try? Does the same error appear at *dmesg*?

Comment: Unfortunately this  is a type-C USB3 connection and I've only 1 port like that on the laptop.

Comment: It seems that the error may have only appeared when you remove and reinsert the device. Is it present after cold booting with the device inserted?  `dmesg | grep -e U1 -e U2`

Comment: Yes it is present

Comment: I suggest you get the driver to load automatically: `sudo -i` and then: `echo r8152  >>  /etc/modules` and finally: `exit` Reboot and check again: `dmesg | grep -e U1 -e U2`

Comment: Si now I see the ethernet interface with ifconfig. But can't make it work, it remain irresponsive. For exmaple: switching off/on networking from the Gnome app make appear the following in dmesg: `[28242.517936] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enx00e04c68048e: Stop submitting intr, status -71`

Comment: I think the message: `Stop submitting intr, status -71` may be normal when networking is disabled. It seems to indicate that networking and therefor the device are not in use and to therefor not continue interrupt transfers. Are there any other clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e r8152 -e enx`

Comment: Sadly dmesg does not show interesting clues. I've also tested to manually setting up IP address but nothing is getting through: `root@xps:~# ifconfig enx00e04c68048e 192.168.1.15 netmask 255.255.255.0
root@xps:~# ping 192.168.1.253
PING 192.168.1.253 (192.168.1.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

Comment: Possibly related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1586195

Comment: Probably too late but this appears to be related to an issue of mine which can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/887036/why-is-the-ethernet-not-working-with-aukey-usb-c-hub